# Does the Lightning port on the Lightning to VGA Adapter have the ability to transmit data?

Tags: lightning, vga-adapter, accessories, mirroring

The Lightning port on the [Lightning to VGA Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD825AM/A/lightning-to-vga-adapter) is used for charging while mirroring.

I want to know if this Lightning port has the ability to transmit data? For example, plug a [Lightning to 3.5 mm Headphone Jack Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMX62AM/A/lightning-to-35-mm-headphone-jack-adapter) into that port, then connect an earphone through this jack adapter. Will the earphone work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - there is not a “lightning hub” or data splitter in that adapter. It functions with signaling limited to negotiate the charge rate only from a power source. That is “data” but not something you could use as an audio out option.

Both screen data and audio data work wirelessly, so you would have choose one to be wired and the other wireless.

In your case with VGA, I would look for a Bluetooth DAC or Bluetooth Amplifier. They run about $30 in the US for decent reliability and cost with an included battery to run the amp.